# error when creating jframe

Tags: user-interface, jframe

help im newbie i always get this error when creating jframe or gui i dont know how to solve this.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.startToolkitThread(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;)Z
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.startToolkitThread(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsDevice.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.makeScreenDevice(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.initGC(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MyJFrame.<init>(Gui1.java:6)
    at Gui1.main(Gui1.java:26)
```

Comment: How are you running your program?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has something to do with with your java installation. Did you receive some message like: Installation failed during java installation. Basically, your IDE is not able to find native java libraries. Please re-install Java on your machine again.

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414425/java-unsatisfiedlinkerror-awt-image)..